# change get and set property of dateTime

Tags: c#, properties

```
public class DateRange
{
    public DateTime From { set { value = value.Date; } get { return this.From; } }
    public DateTime To {get { return this.From.Date.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1); }}
}
```

DateRange is coming from Client-side with different time and I want to 
set time of 'From' to start of the day and 'To' to End of the day

Comment: For one thing the getter for From looks circular. It should return a backing private variable like _from. Need more detail of what you're trying to do.

Comment: To get start of day use the Date property which truncates the hours minutes seconds.  Then end of the day is usually the start of the next day (use less than) so to get start of next day add one day to Date property.

Comment: @jdweng yes I now that but I want DateRange to do it by itself not by me hard coding this solution every time.

Comment: Unfortunately while the requirements are so unclear, it's unlikely that anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: If you just need to check that a date is on a certain day you can compare the `Date` properties of both instead of having a range like `date1.Date == date2.Date`.  I'd expect a `DateRange` class to allow for any valid range where From is less than or equal to To, so at the very least you should rethink the name to something like `ExactlyOneDayRange` or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you arent actually holding the data anywhere. 
You need to create a variable to hold the value:

```
public class DateRange
{
    public DateRange(DateTime from){
        this._from = from.Date;
    }
    private DateTime _from;
    public DateTime From { set { _from = value.Date; } get { return this._from; } }
    public DateTime To {get { return this._from.Date.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1); }}
}
```

One thing to note about the way you had it, the getter from From returned From, which would call the get again, and this would keep happening until you got a StackOverflowException and the program crashed.

In the code about I made a variable called _from which holds the actual value.

The _ convention to indicate a private variable isnt universally accepted. You should find a set of conventions you like and stick to it consistently across the project.